# Why doesn't EF core code first like my composite key?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, composite-primary-key

```
public class UserDocuments
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string UserID { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Key]
    public Guid DocumentID { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    public UserType UserType { get; set; } = UserType.None;
    public int Version { get; set; } = -1;
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserDocuments>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.UserID, x.DocumentID });
}


public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<UserDocuments>("UserDocuments");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

The detail error message I get is

```
"The entity set 'UserDocuments' is based on type
'DocServer2.Shared.Models.UserDocuments' that has no keys defined."
```

I cannot figure what is wrong with my code; I checked related entries here on SO, but cannot see a difference. I don't think that should be the case, but is it a problem to mix string and Guid in a composite key?

Edit [08/07/22]

I need to add [key] annotations to the two properties of UserDocuments that make up the key.

Comment: Could you post exception details? Just click `Copy Details`.

Comment: The exception is from OData model, which is different from EF Core model. You have configured EF Core model composite PK, however this doesn't seem to "flow" automatically to OData model. So, remove EF Core related tags and check/ask for OData model configuration.

Comment: I think the conventions look at data annotations, meaning that you should use KeyAttribute.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097

Comment: Ivan, you cannot do this with data annotations in EF core.

Comment: philip, in this case posting an error message makes sense as it might provide meaningful information why my code doesn't work.

Comment: *you cannot do this with data annotations in EF core* -- What do you mean? What did you try?